# Writing $A(t)=1+S_1S_2^{-1}$ as an Ito diffusion process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Let $W$ be a Wiener process/Brownian motian and let 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}S_1 &= 2S_1(t)dt +3S_1(t) dW\\
\mathrm{d}S_2 &= 4S_2(t)dt +5S_2(t) dW
\end{align}
$$

Now I'd like to write $A(t)=t+S_1 S_2^{-1}$ as an Ito diffusion process.

I'd appreciate any advice/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be specific with your example, it will help to see that
$$\begin{split}
dS_2^{-1}
 &= -S_2^{-2}\left(dS_2\right) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2S_2^{-3} \left(dS_2\right)^2 \\
 &= -\frac{dS_2}{S_2^2} + \frac{\left(dS_2\right)^2}{S_2^3} \\
 &= -\frac{4S_2dt + 5S_2dW}{S_2^2} + \frac{25 S_2^2 dt}{S_2^3} \\
 &= \frac{21dt - 5dW}{S_2}
\end{split}$$
$$\begin{split}
dA
 &= dt + d\left[S_1 S_2^{-1}\right] \\
 &= dt + S_2^{-1} dS_1 + S_1 d S_2^{-1} + \frac{1}{2} dS_1 dS_2^{-1}\\
 &= dt + \frac{S_1(2dt + 3dW)}{S_2}
       + S_1 \frac{21dt - 5dW}{S_2}
       + \frac{S_1(2dt + 3dW)(21dt - 5dW)}{2S_2} \\
 &= dt + \frac{S_1}{S_2} \left(2dt + 3dW + 21dt - 5dW - \frac{15}{2} dt\right)
\end{split}$$
and you can finish the arithmetic....

Comment: Thank youu. No that is not what I meant. I edited the question, to make it more specific. Can you help with that?

Comment: @dae make an edit with your answers. This uses the Ito product rule $$d(XY) = XdY + YdX + \frac{dXdY}{2}$$

Comment: @Did i removed everything, the only material problem is what is after, since that is OP's example. But why didn't they make sense?

Comment: Each functional in them, say $A(t)$ for example, is not a function of $t$ and $W(t)$ hence the partial derivatives would have to be defined precisely--and if one tries to define the partial derivative of $A(t)$ with respect to the path $(W(s))_{0\leqslant s\leqslant t}$, I am afraid one has to rely on Malliavin calculus, which is substantially more complex and not needed at all to answer the question.

Comment: @gt6989b Can i as well conclude smthing about whether $A$ is martingale?

Comment: @Did in all fairness, he did change the question from its original form that the previous form was supposed to answer...

Comment: @dae well, after you do the arithmetic, what expressiondo you get for the drift? What drift is a martingale supposed to have?